# Daemonize after startup in Go

Tags: go, daemon

I have a system I need to operate as a daemon, which has been developed in go. Ordinarily I could just manage this though something like systemd or even just something as simple as '*./project &*' but this particular project needs to get some input before it can become a daemon - it needs a password to be entered.

This password cannot be provided as command line args, placed in a config file, hard coded in the source etc. It must be manually provided by someone who has knowledge of the password at system startup.

At startup, the project needs to collect the password, verify that things are correct, and only if the correct password has been provided (verified by attempting to decrypt a certificate) can it then actually begin to operate as the daemon.

Is there any way in go for the project to startup, accept input from stdin, perform whatever validation is needed etc, and only then become a daemon process (detaching from stdin etc)?

Currently I can simulate the required behavior by starting it, and after the password has been entered using 'ctrl+z' to suspend it and bg to push the process to the background. Surely there has to be a way of doing that from within the process itself...

Comment: You can create another program, the role of that program just send a password to your daemon, you can submit that password by any way (IPC, HTTPS, Redis PUB).

Comment: The usual way to do this is to edit the source code to make the program do what it should have been doing to begin with.

Comment: you are essentially asking how to make a program become a daemon after it has got the password correct

Comment: @MichaelHampton - it is doing what it's supposed to do! There are regulatory requirements surrounding the need for data to be encrypted, and for how the password must be provided.

Comment: @whitespace that's correct.

Comment: @Зелёный that doesn't make the startup and control flow overly streamlined. Now the code has to startup, can't report back at startup that there are any problems etc, wait to get data over some channel trough a different process, and only then be able to see if that's the correct data and either fully start or exit. Solution needs to be self contained. However, using something like this in conjunction with the answer by rogerpales below could work.

Comment: Bettter check with your lawyers, then. Whether you use some workaround as in the answer below, or modify the original program, you may be violating those regulations. And if you aren't, then you could just fix the original program and not worry about workarounds like this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the approach described is the required solution, and is the approved solution as implemented in other systems (developed using C). The regulatory issues are well understood and have been so for many years. They are not the issue. The issue is getting go to do what can easily be done in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

here is a program that does what I think you meant.

so the program only checks the password. The actual daemon is `webserver` which gets called only when password checks out.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "os/exec"
)


func main() {
    pwd, err := terminal.ReadPassword(1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if string(pwd) == "test" {
        c := exec.Command("./webserver")
        c.Run()
    }
    return
}
```

the daemon program I used here was taken from here

https://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon/blob/master/examples/cmd/gd-simple/simple.go

Its not possible to run a single program both as waiting for input and as a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flags and carefully control your app flow and run itself as a daemon if a given flag (such as encrypted credentials) is passed. Or even store them in a temporary file, database or anywhere.

```
func main() {

    cred := flag.String("cred", "", "raw cred")

    flag.Parse()

    if *cred == "" {
        fmt.Print("Enter credentials:\n")
        decryptedCred, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')

        if !validCred(decryptedCred) {
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        encryptedCred := encryptCredentials(decryptedCred)

        cmd := exec.Command("./project", fmt.Sprintf("-cred=%s", encryptedCred), "&")
        cmd.Start()

        fmt.Printf("Started project with pid: %d\n", cmd.Process.Pid)

        os.Exit(0)
    }

    for {
        // start app
        // use *cred here
    }
}
```

Whatever the approach I would probably keep track of the pid, etc.

```
./project
# Enter credentials:
myCredentialsString
# Started project with pid: 11702
ps ax | grep project
# 11667 s001  R      0:02.47 ./project -cred=N/esPq8wsWn4/+Gco16ddl9UnJ0= &\012
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ended up using something like this, but having the credentials sent from the initial process to the main one using a tcp link (net.Listen/net.Dial) - for putting the credentials in as args then even though they are encrypted they could be recovered from ps -ef  - and the encrypted cred value could be reverse engineered by anyone who has access to the source (regulatory controls here are absurdly tight over things like that and this would fail those checks)

Comment: Tried to select this as the answer but don't have the reputation yet to allow that.

Comment: @user2650472 instead of using `flag`, you can use,`golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal`, it has an option to read Password from terminal without echoing back to prompt.